# Creating a new conditional column in a dataframe with values from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with creating a conditional column using values from multiple other columns with pandas.

```
    Column1|Column2|Column4|Column4
       1   |   2   |   5   |   A
       2   |   3   |   4   |   B
       3   |   4   |   3   |   C
       4   |   5   |   2   |   B
       5   |   1   |   1   |   C
```

And what I want is to create a new column such that if column4 is equal to A then the new column will be equal to the value in column1 so the final dataframe would look like this

```
    Column1|Column2|Column4|Column4|column5
       1   |   2   |   5   |   A   |   1
       2   |   3   |   4   |   B   |   3
       3   |   4   |   3   |   C   |   3
       4   |   5   |   2   |   B   |   5
       5   |   1   |   1   |   C   |   1
```

Here is what I have tried so far but keep getting the response data.column1 (x) object is not callable

```
def column5(x):
    if x['column4'] == 'A'
        return data.column1(x)
    elif x['column4'] == 'B'
        return data.column2(x)
    elif x['column4'] == 'C'
        return data.column3(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got error because `data.column1` is a `pandas.Series`, you cannot call it like a function with `data.column1(x)`.

Also your desired value are different for each row based on value of col4, so you will need to use either a loop, or better: using `pandas's apply()` function.

Try this:

```
# map value to column
val_to_col = {
    'A': 'Column1', 
    'B': 'Column2', 
    'C': 'Column3'
}

# get data from col, based on row[col4]
df['column5'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[val_to_col.get(row['Column4'])], axis=1)
```